# Can an orderless set of inner product between N vectors determine unique structure of the vectors?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, matrices, inner-product

Suppose we have n vectors {a1,a2,a3,...,an} such that the sum of them is zero vector

a1+a2+a3+...+an=0

Now, we compute the inner product of each two vectors of them, i.e. we compute the Gramian matrix of them and take the strictly upper triangular part.

Then, we make those inner products into an orderless set.

Now, can we determine a unique structure of the vectors from the set?

For example, when n=3 it's feasible,

Suppose we have 3 vectors {a,b,c} such that a+b+c=0

Then c=-a-b

the set of inner products of them is

{a.b, a.c, b.c}

= {a.b, a.(-a-b), b.(-a-b)}

= {a.b, -a^2-a.b, -b^2-a.b}

Then we can find

a^2 = -(-a^2-a.b+a.b)

b^2 = -(-b^2-a.b+a.b)

Cos<a,b> = a.b/(|a|*|b|)

So we know the length of a and b and the angle between a and b.

And by the condition c=-a-b, the structure of the 3 vectors is unique.

Even if we don't know the order of set of inner products

Suppose they are {k1, k2, k3}

We just need to choose anyone of them like k2

And compute

i=-(k2+k1)

j=-(k2+k3)

Cos<i,j>=k2/(Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[j])

Then the structure is determinate and unique.

So what if n>3?

Note: If one structure can be transformed into the other by reflections, we regard them as same structure